Presenting GroupActivitySharingController using SwiftUI on MacOS
I am trying to present a GroupActivitySharingController using SwiftUI. I am using a NSViewControllerRepresentable:
 struct MeetingGroupActivitySharingRepresentableView: NSViewControllerRepresentable {
    @State var event : Event
   
    func makeNSViewController(context: NSViewControllerRepresentableContext<MeetingGroupActivitySharingRepresentableView>) -> GroupActivitySharingController {
        
        return try! GroupActivitySharingController(MeetingGroupActivity(event: event))
    }
    
    func updateNSViewController(_ nsViewController: GroupActivitySharingController ,  context: NSViewControllerRepresentableContext<MeetingGroupActivitySharingRepresentableView>) {
        print("Updating VC")
    }
}

I present it as following :
.sheet(isPresented: $showGroupActivitySharingView) {
        MeetingGroupActivitySharingRepresentableView(event: observedEvent.event)
 }

It works fine on iOS, however on MacOS, I cannot dismiss the view. I see the following error:
dismissViewController:: Error: maybe this view controller was not presented?
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000019d75accc __exceptionPreprocess + 176
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000019d242788 objc_exception_throw + 60
    2   Foundation                          0x000000019e8cbc6c -[NSCalendarDate initWithCoder:] + 0
    3   AppKit                              0x00000001a145a77c -[NSViewController dismissViewController:] + 224
    4   _GroupActivities_AppKit             0x0000000232d65cf0 $s23_GroupActivities_AppKit0A25ActivitySharingControllerC011dismissViewG06resultyAA0aeF6ResultO_tFyyYaYbScMYccfU_TY0_ + 444
    5   _GroupActivities_AppKit             0x0000000232d67b65 $s23_GroupActivities_AppKit0A25ActivitySharingControllerC011dismissViewG06resultyAA0aeF6ResultO_tFyyYaYbScMYccfU_TATQ0_ + 1
    6   _GroupActivities_AppKit             0x0000000232d68bd9 $sIeghH_ytIeghHr_TRTQ0_ + 1
    7   _GroupActivities_AppKit             0x0000000232d68bdd $sIeghH_ytIeghHr_TRTATQ0_ + 1
    8   _GroupActivities_AppKit             0x0000000232d66931 $sxIeghHr_xs5Error_pIegHrzo_s8SendableRzs5NeverORs_r0_lTRyt_Tg5TQ0_ + 1
    9   _GroupActivities_AppKit             0x0000000232d68ba5 $sxIeghHr_xs5Error_pIegHrzo_s8SendableRzs5NeverORs_r0_lTRyt_Tg5TATQ0_ + 1
    10  libswift_Concurrency.dylib          0x0000000263cfb0f9 _ZL23completeTaskWithClosurePN5swift12AsyncContextEPNS_10SwiftErrorE + 1
)

Any idea what is going on?
